# Get max value by a group of column in SQL/Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have the following columns:

```
code  note
1      10
2      8
1      9
3      5
3      4
```

**How can I get the code that has the max average note?**

My output should be code 1 since the AVGs are 9,5 (code 1), 8 (code 2), 4,5 (code 3)

My query in athena:

```
select  code from table group by code, avg(note) ORDER BY DESC limit 1
```

The output error:

```
GROUP BY clause cannot contain aggregations, window functions or grouping operations
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grouping function must be in your SELECT list of column, not in your GROUP BY clause.

Try this instead:

```sql
select code, avg(note) as avg_of_note
from table 
group by code
order by avg_of_note desc
limit 1
```

Also: I wouldn't personally name a column `code`. I could be concerned it would be a reserved word in some SQL dialects.

Comment: I believe it should be `order by avg_of_note desc`

Comment: @FlexYourData: Yep. Thanks for spotting. Corrected.